# sql Join query in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to join two tables in laravel 5.3 and fetched the value in template page .now i caught error.I have two table names as users and department.`$queries = DB::getQueryLog();` return the query what I want exactly as `select users.*, department.name as dept_name from users inner join department on users.department_id = department.id` for the following query.this will return the error

ErrorException in Macroable.php line 74:
Method links does not exist. (View: C:\wamp64\www\testLaravel\TestTravel\resources\views\approval_view.blade.php)

BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74:
Method links does not exist.

```
controller
class travelApprovalController extends Controller {
public function index(){
//$users = DB::table('passenger')->paginate(2); 
$users = DB::table('users')
        ->join('department', 'users.department_id', '=', 'department.id')

        ->select('users.*', 'department.name as dept_name')
        ->get();   //->paginate(2)
  return view('approval_view',['users'=>$users]);
}

approval.blade.php
@foreach ($users as $user)
     <tr>
        <td>{{ $user->id }}</td>
        <td><a href="#" class="viewPopLink" role="button" data-id="{{ $user->id }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">{{ $user->dept_name }}<a></td>
        <td>{{ $user->dept_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>

    </tr>

     @endforeach
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
{{$users->links()}}
```

Comment: This line gives you error {{$users->links()}} ...

Comment: ya I want to do pagination

Comment: Use datatable for pagination or like this foreach ($users as $user)
  <span>{{ $user->links }}</span>
@endforeach

Comment: shall I add this ->get()->paginate(2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                ->join('department', 'users.department_id', '=', 'department.id')
                ->select('users.*', 'department.name as dept_name')
                ->paginate(2);
```

Comment: I caught SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*, `department`.`name`) as aggregate from `users` inner join `department` on `us' at line 1 (SQL: select count(`users`.*, `department`.`name`) as aggregate from `users` inner join `department` on `users`.`department_id` = `department`.`id`)

Answer (score 2):

Use like this

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
  <tr>
    <td>{{ $user->id }}</td>
    <td><a href="#" class="viewPopLink" role="button" data-id="{{ $user->id }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">{{ $user->dept_name }}<a></td>
    <td>{{ $user->dept_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $user->links }}</td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

OR

```
{{$users[0]->links()}}
```

Comment: I want to do pagination